# Not able to sort the column items in grid

Tags: admin, grid, sorting

I have created a custom grid I am not able to sort the items of a column.(ascending and descending).If i click first time it will sort in ascending order.Second time it will descend the contents.But if i click again same single content will come many times.For example if i have 1 2 3 as ids it will show 1 1 1 3 times.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because of storage config you have to set your primary id as **indexField**

```
<item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
</item>
```

in you data provider **argument**

```
<argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">storepickupGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">tesst_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id_s</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
```

Comment: @Dilip if answer help you. kindly accept answer.